# Wireshark hex escapes not woking while matching payload

Tags: regex, wireshark

In wireshark I was trying to match packets whose payloads does not begin with `00 24`. But for some reason, this filter is failing:

```
not(udp.payload ~ "^\x00\x24")
```

But surprisingly this works:

```
not(udp.payload ~ "^\x00\\x24")
```

and also this:

```
not(udp.payload ~ "^\x00\\\x24")
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2):

The `matches` (or `~`) operator works on strings, not bytes.  Instead, you can either use `contains` or a *comparison* (`==`) operator along with the *slice* (`[]`) operator.

For example:

```
not (udp.payload[0:2] contains 00:24)
```

or:

```
!(udp.payload[0:2] == 00:24)
```

Refer to the [wireshark-filter](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/wireshark-filter.html) man page for more details about these operators.

Comment: That is nice too know. But, although not mentioned in the question, I needed to match regex to payload, something like this: `not(udp.payload ~ "^[\x00-\x0f]\x24")`. I think this is not possible with the syntax you told.

Comment: Also, this does not explain why the filter in question failed.

Comment: What version of Wireshark are you using?  Because this filter works for me using Wireshark 4.0.6 on Windows 10:  `not (udp.payload ~ "^\x00\x24")`.  

As for the new regex expression you provided in your comment, it also seems to work just fine for me.  Perhaps you just need to update your version of Wireshark?

Comment: Are you sure that filter is filtering out packets properly? I mean, that filter is not giving error to me. But it is not filtering out packets properly. Also, I'm on latest version of Wireshark.

Comment: can you check if this is working `"^\x00\x28"`. This regex is upright not compiling for me. To make this work I have to write escape \x28 like this for eg: `"^\x00[\x28]"`.

Comment: OK, I *think* I know what's wrong.  You probably have other protocols in your capture file, so for example a TCP packet will also match that filter.  To fix this, you first want to predicate the search on **only**  the UDP packets.  What happens if you try `udp and not (udp.payload ~ "^\x00\x28")`?

Comment: My laptop is currently not available. Once I get that, I will update the question with relevant screenshots. :)